# Durbin-Watson Critical Values for Large Sample Sizes

Tags: multiple-regression, sample-size, autocorrelation

My sample includes 3,627 observations but I can only find tables displaying critical values for the Durbin-Watson test for sample sizes 2,000 and below.

Where can I find tables for sample sizes exceeeding 2,000 observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a large sample size, the normal approximation of the Durbin-Watson distribution is working well enough. You just need to compute the specific expectiation and variance of the Durbin Watson statistic $d$ given your regressor matrix $X$ under the null distribution. For example, this is implemented in the `dwtest()` function in the R package `lmtest`. Also, that function interfaces a numerical algorithm to compute the exact distribution (depending on $X$) rather than using the tables of upper and lower bounds of critical values.

The `dwtest()` function implements the following formulas, originally taken from the econometrics book of Griffiths, Hill, and Judge, I think. With the usual transformation matrix $A$ (with 2 on the diagonal, except the first and last element, and -1 on the off-diagonals), the test statistic $d$ can be written as: $d = \frac{e^\top A e}{e^\top e}$.

Then, we define to auxiliary quantities $P$ and $Q$:

$P = 2 \cdot (n - 1) - tr(X^\top A X (X^\top X)^{-1})$

$Q = 2 \cdot (3 \cdot n - 4) - 2 \cdot tr(X^\top A^\top A X (X^\top X)^{-1}) + tr(X^\top A X (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top A X (X^\top X)^{-1})$

And with these we can easily compute $E(d) = \frac{1}{n-k} \cdot P$ and
$Var(d) = \frac{2}{(n - k) (n - k + 2)} \cdot (Q - P \cdot E(d))$. The variables $n$ and $k$ are the number of observations and regressors in $X$, respectively, and $tr(\cdot)$ is the trace of a matrix.